# how to toggle this function using my custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to toggle the function but its not working. i don't where im wrong

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4X4t/242/)

**Tried Code**

```
$('.toggledropdown').click(function(e){
 // $('.showdropdowninv',this).toggle('slow');
 $('.showdropdowninv').toggle('slow');
});
```

I need to toggle particular clicked ul but its not working  . Im using this function its not working

something like this

```
$('.showdropdowninv',this).toggle('slow');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "toggle the function"?

Comment: can u check my fiddle toglle both works at the same time. I need to both work seprately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To toggle the display of just the items associated with the clicked anchor, use jQuery's [DOM navigation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to go *up* to the closest parent div, then down to the `.showdropdowninv` item(s) within that div only:

```
$('.toggledropdown').click(function(e){
  $(this).closest('div').find('.showdropdowninv').toggle('slow');
});
```

Updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V4X4t/243/

(Obviously the closest parent element might not be a div in all cases, but it is for the html in your fiddle. You could also select the parent by class, e.g., for your html you could use `.closest('.element-dragging')`.)

(Note also that you could use a similar technique to implement the "Select all" checkboxes for each group.)